# question on time, distance and overtaking

Tags: algebra-precalculus

P, Q and R start from the same place X at (a) kmph, (a+b) kmph and (a+2b) kmph respectively.

If Q starts *p* hours after P, how many hours after Q should R start, so that both Q and R overtake P at the same time?

A. pa/ a + b

B. a/ p (a+b)

C. p(a+b)/ a+2b

D. pa/ a + 2b

Comment: Since $Q$ and $R$ both travel at speed $a+b$, if they ever want to be anywhere (such as right beside $P$) at the same time, they will have to leave at the same time.

Comment: I made a mistake. it is edited now. it was (a+2b) for R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is too late to solve this problem, but I will post my solution anyway since I enjoy these kinds of problems. Set the distances traveled by Q and R equal to each other:

$$ (a + b)(t - p) = (a + 2b)(t - x) $$

Solving this for *x*, we find

$$ x = \frac{bt + p(a + b)}{a + 2b} $$

If we remember that the left side of the first equation is equal to *at*, we find that *bt* is equal to $p(a + b)$. We can substitute this into the equation.

At this point, we should also take into account that *x* is the time between P and R leaving, not Q and R. Accordingly, we need to subtract *p* from the expression for *x*:

$$ x = \frac{2p(a + b)}{a + 2b} - p$$

Combining the fractions and simplifying a bit, you will get one of the answer choices.

Comment: so right. kudos